# Update sqlite3 using variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, sql-update

I want to update a text value in my Database using a variable to determine the value that should be inserted. I tried many different things.

```
cursor.execute ("update Athens_Label_Table set " + category + " =" + self.create_entry.get())

cursor.execute ("update Athens_Label_Table set " + category + " = s% ", (self.create_entry.get())
```

Those two always make the program crash or tell me that there is a syntax mistake. I want the value in the "category" column to be replaced by self.create_entry.get().

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: The second version is correct, but you're missing a comma to make the parameters a tuple, and you're missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: `(self.create_entry.get(),))`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I applied your recommended improvements. Now the program does not crash anymore but it shows me the following error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input".     Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: `= s%` should be `= ?`. Sqiite uses `?` as the placeholder, `%s` is for MySQL.

Comment: Thanks man youre the best! ;)